# Exterior Derivatives and Wedge Product

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

I'm having trouble grasping the use of the wedge product in (what I think is) an exterior derivative. I found this following equation on the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), but am not sure if I was applying it correctly: [image]

Is this the proper way to solve an exterior derivatives problem, like the first example below? And how would you solve the second part?

Example--

Consider the following differential form fields on $ℝ^3$:
$ = ^3 −4x^2  $ and $= ^3 ∧  +sin  ∧$

1. Find the derivative $$.

I attempted the following, but it doesn't make much sense to me:

$= \frac{∂}{∂x}(z^3) ∧∧ + \frac{∂}{∂y}(z^3) y∧∧ + \frac{∂}{∂x}(sinz) ∧∧ + \frac{∂}{∂z}(sinz) z∧∧z$

so $= 0$..?

<s>$= 0 + 0 + 0+ (cosz)∧∧z$</s>

$= (cosz)∧∧z$

Is that correct? If so what does that result mean?

2. Find $∧$.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this part.

Comment: We can't tell if you apply it correctly, if you don't show your work.

Comment: apologies, updated.

Comment: You're missing a term in $d\beta$. What's more, you are forgetting the $dx_i$ that goes with each $\partial/\partial x_i$

Comment: As for computing $\alpha\wedge\beta$, you can do it term by term, and put the coefficient functions as factors (just like you would do with a tensor product)

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do I apply the $dx_i$? By placing it like so: $dβ=(cosz)∧ dx_i ∧dx∧dz$? What does $dx_i$ represent?

Comment: Yes. $x_i$ is a variable, so in your case, it stands for either $x$, $y$ or $z$

Comment: Ok, so in the first term would it be z? E.g. $\frac{∂}{∂x}(z^3) dz∧dx∧dy$.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the result 0? Because the final term would be $(cosz)dz∧dx∧dz$ which contains $dz∧dz=0$. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. The $dx_i$ should be with $\partial/\partial x_i$. So your example gives $\frac{\partial z^3}{\partial x }dx\wedge dx\wedge dy$.

Comment: Hm. I updated the question with my new approach but it still looks like the $\frac{∂}{∂z}(sinz)dz∧dx∧dz$ term becomes 0. Which then makes the final result 0

Comment: The sum goes over all possible variables, ie $x$, $y$ and $z$ in this case

Comment: Rather than trying to learn from wikipedia, you might take a look at the appropriate lectures in my course posted on YouTube (link in my profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\green#1{\color{limegreen}{#1}}
\def\blue#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\orange#1{\color{orange}{#1}}
$

Let $\alpha = x^3dx − 4x^2ydz$ and $\beta= z^3 dx\wedge dy  +\sin (z) dx\wedge dz$ as in your question.

First to compute $d\beta$:

$$
\begin{align}
d\beta &= d(z^3dx\wedge dy) + d(\sin(z)dx\wedge dz)\\
&=\frac{\partial z^3}{\partial x}dx\wedge dx\wedge dy + \frac{\partial z^3}{\partial y}dy\wedge dx\wedge dy+\frac{\partial z^3}{\partial z}dz\wedge dx\wedge dy\\
&\hspace{.5cm}+\frac{\partial \sin(z)}{\partial x}dx\wedge dx\wedge dz+\frac{\partial \sin(z)}{\partial y}dy\wedge dx\wedge dz+\frac{\partial \sin(z)}{\partial z}dz\wedge dx\wedge dz\\
&=3z^2dz\wedge dx\wedge dy\,,\\
d\beta&= 3z^2 dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\,.
\end{align}$$

Now let's look at $\alpha\wedge \beta$:
$$\begin{align}
\alpha\wedge\beta&=(\red{x^3dx}-\green{4x^2ydz})\wedge(\blue{z^3dx\wedge dy} + \orange{\sin(z)dx\wedge dz})\\
&=\red{x^3dx}\wedge(\blue{z^3dx\wedge dy}+\orange{\sin(z) dx\wedge dz})\\
&\hspace{.5cm}-\green{4x^2ydz}\wedge(\blue{z^3dx\wedge dy}+\orange{\sin(z) dx\wedge dz})\\
&=\red{x^3}\blue{z^3}\red{dx}\wedge \blue{dx\wedge dy} +\red{x^3}\orange{\sin(z)}\red{dx}\wedge\orange{ dx\wedge dz}\\
&\hspace{.5cm}-\green{4x^2y}\blue{z^3}\green{dz}\wedge \blue{dx\wedge dy}+\green{4x^2y}\orange{\sin(z)}\green{dz}\wedge \orange{dx\wedge dz}\\
&=-\green{4x^2y}\blue{z^3dx\wedge dy}\wedge \green{dz}
\end{align}$$